# How to split string into two parts based on last "/"

Tags: java, android, string, split

I want to split a string into two parts so that i can get file path and file name.

Here is my file path...

```
String totalString = "/mnt/sdcard/PDF/abc.pdf"
String filename = "";String filePath = "";
filename = totalString.substring(files.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

filePath = ?

i am not getting how to get filePath = "/mnt/sdcard/PDF/"?

How to do that?

Comment: you can use substring for both [check](http://ideone.com/3IJijS)

Comment: Just use the File class. File f = new File(filename); String name = f.getName(); String path = f.getParent.getAbsolutePath();

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of manipulating string you can use `File` class which can give you all informations you need:

```
String totalString = "/mnt/sdcard/PDF/abc.pdf";
File f = new File(totalString);
String filename = f.getName();
String filePath = f.getParent();
System.out.println(filename);
System.out.println(filePath);
```

Output:

```
abc.pdf
\mnt\sdcard\PDF
```

As you see *parent*s elements are split with `\` instead of `/` but this shouldn't be a problem if you are going to use it as argument for Java application which also uses `File`s.

Answer (score 3):

```
filePath = totalString.substring(0, totalString.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

Comment: although @Pshemo's answer is what one must use but this one is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
String totalString = "/mnt/sdcard/PDF/abc.pdf";
String[] str=totalString.split("/");
String filename = ""

for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
    if(str[i].endsWith(".pdf")){
        filename=str[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `string.split` function.

```
String totalString = "/mnt/sdcard/PDF/abc.pdf";
String[] parts = totalString.split("(?<=/)(?=[^/]*$)");
String path = parts[0];
String filename = parts[1];
System.out.println(path);
System.out.println(filename);
```

**Output:**

```
/mnt/sdcard/PDF/
abc.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String totalString = "/mnt/sdcard/PDF/abc.pdf";
String filename = "";String filePath = "";
String[] splitted = totalString.split("/");
int i = 0;
for (int i; i < (splitted.length - 1); i++) {
    filePath += splitted[i];
}
filename = splitted[i];
```